# MongoDB indexes for field existence?

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing

Say I have a collection with millions of documents, some of which have a field like `myField` in the example below:

```
{
   ...
   myField: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse suscipit, lectus pharetra sodales cursus, purus nunc tristique urna, vel bibendum purus nisl non ipsum. Aenean porta porttitor mauris, vitae bibendum augue luctus vitae. Fusce non posuere quam. Mauris bibendum elit orci, et pretium quam faucibus sit amet. Vivamus nec congue sem, in commodo nisi. Pellentesque dapibus neque eget sem elementum, non pellentesque erat sagittis. Morbi et scelerisque orci. Etiam sed augue orci. Aliquam feugiat, arcu non aliquet sagittis, ante enim lacinia purus, quis lacinia leo leo id diam. Curabitur rutrum, eros in gravida efficitur, justo sem finibus dui, at lacinia nulla neque non nulla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse suscipit, lectus pharetra sodales cursus, purus nunc tristique urna, vel bibendum purus nisl non ipsum. Aenean porta porttitor mauris, vitae bibendum augue luctus vitae. Fusce non posuere quam. Mauris bibendum elit orci, et pretium quam faucibus sit amet. Vivamus nec congue sem, in commodo nisi. Pellentesque dapibus neque eget sem elementum, non pellentesque erat sagittis. Morbi et scelerisque orci. Etiam sed augue orci. Aliquam feugiat, arcu non aliquet sagittis, ante enim lacinia purus, quis lacinia leo leo id diam. Curabitur rutrum, eros in gravida efficitur, justo sem finibus dui, at lacinia nulla neque non nulla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse suscipit, lectus pharetra sodales cursus, purus nunc tristique urna, vel bibendum purus nisl non ipsum. Aenean porta porttitor mauris, vitae bibendum augue luctus vitae. Fusce non posuere quam. Mauris bibendum elit orci, et pretium quam faucibus sit amet. Vivamus nec congue sem, in commodo nisi. Pellentesque dapibus neque eget sem elementum, non pellentesque erat sagittis. Morbi et scelerisque orci. Etiam sed augue orci. Aliquam feugiat, arcu non aliquet sagittis, ante enim lacinia purus, quis lacinia leo leo id diam. Curabitur rutrum, eros in gravida efficitur, justo sem finibus dui, at lacinia nulla neque non nulla.",
   ...
}
```

I would like to be able to perform a query that returns records where the field `myField` exists.  I can do this by creating an index on `myField`, but the index is quite large and is really being underutilized since I am only checking for field existence.

Is there a way to create an index that would only be used to check if the field exists (and not value matching)?  I looked into [partial indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#index-type-partial), and while interesting, I can't see how they would apply here.

Comment: why you are not using $exists operator?

Comment: @Sachin - to do what?  Just to clarify - I'm not asking how to query the records where the field exists.  This question is specific to the content of the indexes, not querying data.

Comment: Afaik, if you don't want to have a big index the only way around is creating an aux boolean field (true if myField exists, false if not) and then indexing it. Those queries should then target the boolean field instead.

Comment: @joao - yeah that's what we are doing now.  Was hoping there was a cleaner way.

Comment: Have you tried using a [hashed index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-hashed/) for this?  That should dramatically reduce the size of the index.

Comment: That's an interesting idea @JohnnyHK.  You don't need to setup sharding when you use Hashed indexes?

Comment: @AbeMiessler No, while hashed indexes support sharding, they don't require it. Basically you're just indexing the hashed value instead of the whole string. However, when I tried an `$exists: true` query with it as a test just now, it wouldn't use the index unless I forced it with [`hint`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for [Sparse indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/)

Comment: They recommend that you use partial indexes in the current version of MongoDB, which I have already looked into.  It might make a very minor improvement, but not really what i'm looking for.